# Simple awk script to find machines with UPS

Tags: awk

I have a file listing the names and locations of all machines on our small network and whether or not they have a uninterruptible power supply (UPS). The file has the format

```
alpha % in office 1 %
beta  % in office 2 %UPS
gamma % in office 1 % 
delta % in reception %UPS
```

I can easily find the machine name and location in an awk one-liner using the command line
`awk -F '%' '/UPS/ {print $1, $2}' $HOME/network_file` where $HOME is  an environmental variable.

However, I would like to write an awk script to add some additional features. I have tried the following

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
FS="%";
OFS=" ";
print "The following computers in the department have UPS \n";
print "Computer\tLocation";
}

{
if (~/UPS/) {print $1,$2;} $HOME/network_file
}
```

This does not work and I get the several error messages including
BEGIN: command not found
 line 37: print: command not found
 line 38: print: command not found
 line 39: syntax error near unexpected token `}'

Desired output

```
The following computers in the department have UPS
Computer Location
beta in office 2
delta in reception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the shebang and just write a SHELL script that calls awk on the file you want:

```
/usr/bin/awk -F'%' '
BEGIN {
   print "The following computers in the department have UPS \n"
   print "Computer\tLocation"
}
/UPS/ {print $1,$2}
' "$HOME/network_file"
```

and if you're on Solaris be aware that /usr/bin/awk is old, broken awk which you must never use - use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk instead.

Note also that I got rid of all of the null statements (spurious trailing semi-colons).

Answer (score 2):

The script should start with

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
```

(That's a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).)

Comment: I can't believe I omitted the shebang. The problem I am having now comes from `if (~/UPS/) {print $1,$2;} $HOME/network_file` which is giving me a syntax error at the tilda

Comment: That would be just `(/UPS/)`, no `~`, but you have bigger problems in that you're trying to use a shbang to execute an awk script but including the file name which is part of the syntax of a SHELL script that would invoke awk. I'll post an answer....

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# script follows
BEGIN ....
```

in one *executable* file. The first line in the file (`#!...`) directs Unix to use the nominated executable (`/usr/bin/awk`) to run the rest of the file (your `awk` script)

Comment: The `-f` is actually needed; the shebang causes the kernel to pass the script file as the next argument. Without `-f`, Awk wants a script's actual text as a command line argument.

Comment: @BrianAgnew can't believe I omitted the shebang. The problem I am having now comes from if (~/UPS/) {print $1,$2;} $HOME/network_file which is giving me a syntax error at the tilda